# Null pointer-exception (FunctionTypeList.ascx) i Composer module-plugin for EPiServer

Tags: episerver

I have installed the Composer-module for EPiServer on an EPiServer CMS 6 R2-site deployed at IIS 7.
I have configured the web.config according to the instructions.
I can view a page in 'Composer edit'-mode.

I get the following error when I try to access the Composer-plugin in Admin-mode (which is used to register Composer-blocks).

How do I solve this?:
    Server Error in '/' Application.
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:


Line 60:                             <ItemTemplate>
Line 61:                                 <nobr>  
Line 62:                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
Line 63:                                         ToolTip ='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description")%>'
Line 64:                                         Text = '<%# Utils.TrimDescription(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description").ToString(),20).ToHtmlEncoded()%>'/>         


Source File: c:\EPiServer\Sites\Skien\Dropit\Plugin\Extension\UI\Admin\Controls\FunctionTypeList.ascx    Line: 62

Stack Trace:


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP.dropit_plugin_extension_ui_admin_controls_functiontypelist_ascx.__DataBinding__control19(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\EPiServer\Sites\Skien\Dropit\Plugin\Extension\UI\Admin\Controls\FunctionTypeList.ascx:62
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +303
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +12659735
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +321
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +12659735
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +321
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +295
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +4780
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +95
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +222
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +313
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +12659735
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +321
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +12659735
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +321
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +12659735
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +321
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +12659735
   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +321
   Dropit.Extension.UI.Admin.Controls.FunctionTypeList.DataBind() +646
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post by Mari Jørgensen](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Mari-Jorgensen/Dates/2010/8/Composer-and-PageTypeBuilder---continued/) describes the same issue on some of the other controls in Composer.

> Basically EPiServer will return an empty string if the Description is not set, while PageTypeBuilder returns null.

The solution is to modify the line of code to return `string.Empty` if the Description is null:

```
<%# Utils.TrimDescription(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description") as string ?? String.Empty,20).ToHtmlEncoded()%>'/>
```